# Get @@ROWCOUNT value before SELECT casting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

MSSQL2016

I need to filter out from cursor those selects not returning a result in order not to send out empty emails. As internal select result is being html-formatted and cast, the check

> IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0

is always true. Better said, it is always

> @@ROWCOUNT = 1

whatever the rows actually returned by the select.

Is it possible to get the actual select row count (before the casting) as a temporary parameter to be passed onto the subsequent EXEC sp_send_mail yes/no check?

```
OPEN C1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
    @WishListID, @userEmail, @category, @range, @geoid, @searchCity, @userName, @GeoLocation
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
            SET @tableHTML =  
            N'<H4>Hello ' +  @userName + '<H4>Here''s your Daily Digest</H4>' +  
            N'<table border="0">' +  
            N'<tr><th>Department</th>' +  
            N'<th>Name</th><th>Description</th>' +  
            N'<th>Place</th></tr>' +  
            CAST ( ( SELECT td = c.Name, '',  
                    td = p.Name, '',  
                    td = p.Description, '',
                    td = @searchCity
              FROM Products as p 
                    JOIN Categories AS c ON p.CategoryID = c.ID
                    JOIN AspNetUsers AS u ON p.UserID = u.Id
                    JOIN GeoData_ALL AS g ON u.GeoID = g.ID
                    WHERE p.IsApproved = 1 AND p.IsDeleted = 0 AND p.DateExpire > convert(date, getdate()) 
                    AND (@geoid = 0 or g.GeoLocation.STDistance(@GeoLocation) <= (@range*5000))
                    AND (@category = 0 or p.CategoryID = @category)
                    ORDER BY p.ID
                     FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
                ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +  
                N'</table>' ;       

                IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 

                EXEC sp_send_mail
                @from='news@xyz.com',
                @to = @userEmail,  
                @subject = 'Weekly xyz Digest',  
                @body = @tableHTML,  
                @bodytype = 'htmlbody',
                @output_mesg = @out_mesg output, 
                @output_desc = @out_desc output ;  

    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
    @WishListID, @userEmail, @category, @range, @geoid, @searchCity, @userName, @GeoLocation

    END
    CLOSE C1;
DEALLOCATE C1;
```

Comment: I'd take that select and use it in an IF EXISTS()

Comment: i think one way is to check the select part of the query before `tablehtml`

Comment: It looks like using IF EXISTS() inside the cast does not fix how to check whether the sp_send_mail should fire or not, while moving the select outside the cast and assigning it to a temp variable to be checked was my 1st idea. In any case I am not a SQL specialist (that's why I am asking): could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Well no... you'd need it outside the cast, of course. The point is to see if that select returns anything before building the HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, you can simply use a SELECT COUNT(*) query before doing anything else in the cursor loop.

Perhaps a neater way to do what you are trying to do, however, is to check for the existence of the value of `@searchCity` in the value of `@tableHTML`, instead of checking for `@@ROWCOUNT>0`

---

To answer what I think you're trying to ask, which would be something like, "If I have a `SET @var='some text' + SELECT SomeStuff` statement, can I find out afterwards how many rows were in the SELECT?"

The answer to that is No.   Well, not without parsing and analyzing the value of the variable that you added the SELECT results to.   You could always count the number of `<tr>`'s in the string you populated.

Comment: All provided parameters could be null or zero valued, and  searchCity makes no exception. But that suggested me to just check for IF @tableHTML != ''. No rows equals empty tableHTML: so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can just do

```
select 1
```

to populate @rowcount